# How to fix a problem with drag and drop JS?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

With this code I want to drag and drop image.
When I drop, for each element I call with ajax a php page to creare a record in db.
Ajax return to me a data.object to put the element in my html page.

I have this JS code to control a drag and drop files from computer...

```
var listaId = new Array();

function dropHandler(ev) {

  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();

  var div = document.getElementById('raccoltaFile');
  var percorso = div.getAttribute('data-percorso');
  var id = div.getAttribute('data-id');

  if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
      // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
      if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
        var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
    var foto = new FormData();

    foto.append('fotoOggetto', file);
    foto.append('nome', file.name);
    foto.append('percorso', percorso);
    foto.append('idSottocat', id);

    $.ajax({
            url: '../php/model.php?az=dragDropImage&id='+id+"&percorso="+percorso,
        data:foto,
        processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data){
        if(data.doc_id) {
        $("#raccoltaFile").append("<div class='row' style='border-bottom: solid 2px grey'><div class='col-3'><img class='img-thumbnail' src='"+data.doc_url+"' /></div><div class=col-4>"+data.doc_nome_file+"</div><div class='col-3'><button class='btn btn-danger' onClick='cancellaFotoProvvisoria()'>Elimina</button></div></div>");
        listaId.push(data.doc_id);
        } else {
        alert("Hai inserito un'immagine fuori dai parametri accettati");
        }

        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert("Qualcosa è andato storto.");
        });

      }
    }  
  }
  alert(listaId);
}
```

The first element id I drag and drop does not enter to listaId array but the second one yes.
You say why?

Comment: Did you check the ajax response `data` / `data.doc_id` ? Maybe adding a `console.log(data)` in the `.done()` function would help find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but ajax response good. I don't know why the first element don't go in the array...